# How to create a Button with Icon and text in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, button, text, icons

I tried to create a button with text and icon. First I tried it in HTML.

```
    <button>
      <img src="img/favicon.png" alt="Image" width="30px" height="30px" >
      Button Text
    </button>
```

Second I tried it with TypeScript.

```
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src=`img/${favicon.png}`;
    btn.appendChild(img);
    btn.textContent=label;
```

After I added the label the Icon will not apear.

My Solution is now

```
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const img=document.createElement("img");
    img.src=`img/${favicon.png}`;
    btn.appendChild(img);
    const span=document.createElement("span");
    btn.appendChild(span)
    span.textContent=label
```

...

But with this solution I have other problems.
Know anyone a better solution? I don't want to use awesome

[image: created with pur HTML]

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why and how the simple HTML approach didn't work...?

Comment: `But with this solution I have other problems` and those are...?

Comment: Can you please share more info

Comment: If the answer by @Billuc solved your problem, please select their answer as the accepted one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first JS solution does not work because setting textContent removes everything that was in the button. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent

In order to recreate what you did with HTML using JS, you can use the Text object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Text

Here a repl : https://replit.com/@billuc/IconButton#index.html

Code :

```js
    const btn = document.createElement("button");
    const img = document.createElement("img");
    const text = new Text(" Button text");
    img.src = `img/favicon.png`;
    img.alt = "Icon";
    img.width = "10";
    img.height = "10";
    btn.appendChild(img);
    btn.appendChild(text);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
```